# Symfony projects messing up the cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have two Symfony projects on same server.

**Project 1** exists under:

```
/myhomedirectory/myproject/ (Symfony 2.1)
```

**Project 2** exists under:

```
/myhomedirectory/myotherproject/ (Symfony 2.0)
```

I've been having 503 errors where the requests actually loads content, but the response code is 503.

Looking at the logs, it seems that **Project 1** is loading code from **Project 2**... Does anybody know how that is possible?

```
PHP   1. {main}() /myhomedirectory/myproject/www/app.php:0
PHP   2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache->handle() /myhomedirectory/myproject/www/app.php:22
PHP   3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\EsiResponseCacheStrategy->update() /myhomedirectory/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php:206
PHP   4. min() /myhomedirectory/myotherproject/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php:68 
PHP Warning:  min(): Array must contain at least one element in /myhomedirectory/myotherproject/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php on line 70
```

[HttpCache.php#L206](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/2.1/HttpCache/HttpCache.php#L206) calling this
[line 70 on version 2.0](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/2.0/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L70) instead of [the function on same project, which is 2.1](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/2.1/HttpCache/EsiResponseCacheStrategy.php#L70).

So code is being mixed... does anybody know how that is possible?

Comment: both 2.0 and 2.1 versions are deprecate and no longer recieve security fixes for almost a year now. I really recommend to update your application as there are prone to public available security leaks now

Comment: You should consider an update of Symfony. I guess composer is going to be a huge help for both projects. It looks like an autoloading crossover.